# How to use DragDropHelper from fluentUI / office-ui-fabric?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

FluentUI (aka office-ui-fabric) has a helper class named [DragDropHelper](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/tree/76326a9ca3061f631b3893292e2cf6c930d6d12e/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/utilities/dragdrop). Unfortunately there isn't any documentation, and I don't really understand how I'm expected to use it.

A short example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/examples/detailslist/draganddrop?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest) (click on the "show code").

Specifically look at the implementation of _getDragDropEvents and the _insertBeforeItems.